# Remove elements JSON jquery

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON like this:

```
[{"name":"tanggalPengajuan","value":""},{"name":"namaPemohon","value":""},{"name":"unitKerja","value":""},{"name":"nomorTelepon","value":""}]
```

How can I remove the elements **value** and **name**
so i will get 'normal JSON` like this:

```
[{
    "tanggalPengajuan" :"my date here",
    "namaPemohon" :"My name here",
    "unitKerja" :"My unit here",
    "nomorTelepon" :"my number here"
}]
```

Comment: How is the JSON generated? If you control that code, I'd modify that to create the structure you want to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this.

For every element in the original array, you can create a new object which has property `name` and value as `value`.

```js
var data = [{"name":"tanggalPengajuan","value":"abc"},{"name":"namaPemohon","value":""},{"name":"unitKerja","value":""},{"name":"nomorTelepon","value":""}];

console.log(data.map(function(t){
  var obj = {};
  obj[t.name] = t.value;
  return obj;
}));
```

Comment: omg, this is very simple, i never thinking, i must push data in new obj,  that's is good idea, but thankyou

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, you can use [`array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`destructuring syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const data = [{"name":"tanggalPengajuan","value":""},{"name":"namaPemohon","value":""},{"name":"unitKerja","value":""},{"name":"nomorTelepon","value":""}];
const result = data.map(({name, value}) => ({[name]:value}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```